# rcp Vs rsync prompting for password

Tags: linux, rsync, rcp

This might be a repeat question but exact explanation I am not getting. I am new to LINUX environment. 
I was trying to copy files from one system to other system. If I issue `rcp` command it copies without asking for password but if I issue `rsync` command then it asking for permission. Can you please explain why?

Comment: Command lines would be useful, as would the "asking for permission" prompt you're seeing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rcp` is an ancient and insecure program for copying files between remote machines.  Avoid it.  `scp` (of the `ssh` suite) is the secure, modern alternative.

`rsync` is a relatively recent program.  When connecting remotely, it uses `ssh` in the background which, being secure, is what is asking for credentials.